# What's inside Linux kernel sysfs holders directory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, sysfs

What exactly is under the `/sys/module/<module_name>/holders` directory? From what I see it's all symlinks. But symlinks representing what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those symlinks link to modules using the given module. You can see them using `lsmod` too. For example, on my system, `lsmod` shows (among many others)

```
ip6_tables             32768  1 ip6table_nat
```

This means that the `ip6_tables` module is loaded, and that it’s used by the `ip6table_nat`. This is also represented under `/sys/modules`:

```
$ ls -l /sys/module/ip6_tables/holders
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 Jan  4 09:29 ip6table_nat -> ../../ip6table_nat
```